# Three JS Level Horizon Camera

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've dug around everywhere looking for a solution to this. It seems that on OrbitControls and TrackballControlls the camera wont stay horizontal! As you move around with TrackballControlls the scene starts to roll. OrbitControlls dragging from left to right only rolls the scene. I'd like to be able to use the TrackballControls but keep the camera level with the horizon when moving around the center of the scene. Is this possible?

My code:

```
    // SETUP GLOBAL VARIABLES

    var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
    // PLANET PHYSICAL LOCATIONS
    var sun, mercPL, venPL, earthPL, marsPL, jupPL, satPL, urPL, nepPL;
    // TIME, AND SCALARS
    var now, scalar, planetScalar;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100000 );
        camera.position.z = 200;

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        //controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // add this only if there is no animation loop (requestAnimationFrame)
        controls.enableDamping = true;
        controls.dampingFactor = 0.8;
        controls.enableZoom = true;




        // ADD THE SUN PHYSICAL LOCATION
        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 30, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "Yellow"});
        sun = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(sun);

        var segmentCount = 32,
            radius = 80,
            geometry = new THREE.Geometry(),
            material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF });

        for (var i = 0; i <= segmentCount; i++) {
            var theta = (i / segmentCount) * Math.PI * 2;
            geometry.vertices.push(
                new THREE.Vector3(
                    Math.cos(theta) * radius,
                    Math.sin(theta) * radius,
                    0));            
        }
        scene.add(new THREE.Line(geometry, material));

        var segmentCount2 = 32,
            radius2 = 120,
            geometry2 = new THREE.Geometry(),
            material2 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF });

        for (var i = 0; i <= segmentCount2; i++) {
            var theta = (i / segmentCount2) * Math.PI * 2;
            geometry2.vertices.push(
                new THREE.Vector3(
                    Math.cos(theta) * radius2,
                    Math.sin(theta) * radius2,
                    0));            
        }

        scene.add(new THREE.Line(geometry2, material2));

        //

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
        //

        render();



    }

    function onWindowResize() {

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    }


    function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();

            render(); // MUST BE HERE FOR ANIMATION

    }


    function render() {

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this can help you ( all the options are commented in the orbit library)

Level Horizon:

```
controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
```

Focus of Orbit:

```
controls.target = (cube.position);
```

Result: (Note: My mouse controls are inverted (Orbit Right / Pan Left) )

[Three.js Lock Orbit Controls](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/NRQRNV?editors=0010)

Edit: After reviewing your comments code, I think this is what you want:

[Three.js Orbit Controls pt 2.](http://codepen.io/k3no/pen/mrNgwj?editors=0011)

The gist is that :

a) you need to provide the camera with an up vector:

```
camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
```

And

b) Target the sun with the camera:

```
camera.lookAt(sun.position);
```

You can still play with the damping, and lock the angles ( there are also vertical constraints if you need them) and speed up down the yaw, but I hope this gets you closer.

Comment: That isn't what I'm going for. I'm looking for this kind of interaction: http://minorplanetcenter.com/db_search/show_orbit?utf8=✓&number=&designation=2016+NP21&name=&epoch=2016-07-31.0&peri=171.3873438&m=349.42313&node=144.6257306&incl=33.4926092&e=0.154857744&a=2.615223&commit=Interactive+Orbit+Sketch

Comment: Btw that link is broken and copy/pasting it results in a broken page. After digging into that site and finding a working example, it's not really clear what interaction you're referring to. The Yaw rotation via the slider control? @Keno's answer seems to fit what you're asking. Note he mentions the mouse controls are inverted -- use the right-mouse-button to orbit -- not sure if you noticed that.

Comment: I added my code above. It is not working how I'd like it to. Those lines seem to only lock the scene from being able to move up and down? Thanks :)

Comment: It seems to be working right actually. For some reason my sun and orbits are rotated 90 degrees off from how the camera is orbiting. How does that happen?

Comment: @rankind: Edited my answer, that is a different question I think, but it involves rotating the camera (giving it an up vector) , see the example.

Comment: Okay, that seems to have done it. Thank you very much!